# Dividing a field into parcels

Tags: qgis

I would need to create a grid consisting of 6 columns and 16 rows in a plot of land. I know the width and length of the land parcel (plot has a size of 82m x 194m) but I don't know how to create a grid that has these characteristics.

I've tried using the create lattice option, but I can't get any success. Could you please tell me how to do it?

I am attaching a picture of the plot of land and proof of the lattice I made - wrong lattice.

[image]